# Asus N61JQ AMD 5730 graphics drivers black screen

Tags: ati

Hardware:

- Asus N61JQ
- ATI Radeon HD 5730

I have managed to install the drivers using the guide on this website without any issues or errors.

The issue is that every time I restart the laptop it gives me the purple screen of ubuntu then I get a black screen. I can hear ubuntu starting in the background but there is no picture whatsoever. I have reinstalled ubuntu and then installed using another guide through the terminal and same result. No errors but I get a black screen.

Comment: Which guides where you following? Can you post links here.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Comment: Thats the guide i used. It worked well, no problems with install.

Comment: I am still getting the black screen. Is there a way to remove the drivers and go back to the old ones without reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe the section "Update Failure" https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure once done with those steps use `apt-get remove` + the driver name to uninstall the drivers - then try purging and reinstalling `xorg`, `apt-get remove --purge xorg` and `apt-get install xorg`

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread randomly and saw that no one answered regarding the black screen (that I saw, apologies if I'm being blind). I think I know the problem because I have the same laptop and, failing many times in trying to update the graphics driver, found that anything past CCC 13.4 (I think) for me turned the backlight off of the laptop display. Considering you can hear Ubuntu in the background, it sounds like everything is loading up fine... You just can't see it. Not very helpful.

Anyway, I know this is an old thread but thought I would share my insights in case it helps anyone else :)

Oh and I got in touch with ASUS to see whether they could offer any help as to which driver is best suited, they simply directed me to their woefully out of date driver page for the laptop.

Cheers